# Moment of Z (about 0) in Arcsine distribution

Tags: self-study, distributions, moments

Moments of **Z** (about 0) are

$E(Z^n)=\int\limits_0^{\pi/2}\frac{2}{\pi}sin^{2n}\theta d\theta=\prod\limits_{j=0}^{n-1}\frac{2j+1}{2j+2}$

Would any stats expert explain me how the R.H.S is arrived at?

Comment: Substituting $x=\sin^2(\theta)$ gives $(1/\pi)\int_0^1 x^{n-1/2}(1-x)^{-1/2}dx$. The integral is the normalizing factor for a [Beta distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_distribution) and therefore equals $B(n+1/2, 1/2).$ This holds true even when $n$ is non-integral, thereby generalizing the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is more a math question than a stats question.  Define for positive integers $m$,

$$\begin{align*} I(m) &= \int \sin^m \theta \, d\theta \\ &= \int \sin^{m-1} \theta \sin \theta \, d\theta \\ &= -\sin^{m-1} \theta \cos \theta + (m-1) \int \cos^2 \theta \sin^{m-2} \theta \, d\theta \\ &= -\sin^{m-1} \theta \cos \theta + (m-1)(I(m-2) - I(m)). \end{align*}$$   Consequently, $$m I(m) = -\sin^{m-1} \theta \cos \theta + (m-1)I(m-2),$$ which is the familiar reduction formula for powers of sine.  It follows that $$\begin{align*} J(2n) &= \int_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} \sin^{2n} \theta \, d\theta \\ &= \frac{1}{2n} \left[-\sin^{2n-1} \theta \cos \theta \right]_{\theta = 0}^{\pi/2} + \frac{2n-1}{2n} J(2n-2) \\ &= \frac{2n-1}{2n} J(2n-2), \end{align*}$$ and since $J(0) = \pi/2$ trivially, we immediately have $$\frac{2}{\pi} J(2n) = \prod_{k=1}^n \frac{2k-1}{2k},$$ which is equivalent to your product.